# How to dynamically find a class by its method implementation?

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I have a list of classtypes. I want to find a specific class that is eligible for processing a distinct value.

In the following example, each implementation must provide a `supports(String)` method. And define which values are supported by this class.

Problem: I don't have *objects* in the list, but *classtypes*. Thus I cannot call custom methods like `supports()` on them.

```
List<Class<MyService>> list;

public Object getInstanceThatSupports(String val) {
   val = "TEST";

   for (Class<MyService> c : list) {
       if (c.supports(val)) { //TODO this is invalid
           return c.newInstance().process(val);
       }
   }
}

public interface MyService {
    boolean supports(String val);
    void process(String val);
}

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
   @Override
   public boolean supports(String val) {
         return val.equals("TEST");
   }

   @Override
   public void process(String val) {
      //handle the value
   }
}
```

How could I else achieve this?

Comment: using reflection can be the way but it is not very clear what you want

Comment: Well. If my input value is `TEST`, I want to find the `MyService` implementation that supports that value. It is defined by `supports(val)` method. But I cannot call the method on the classtype, so I cannot find it out this way.

Comment: You can create a new instace and call it `c.newInstance().supports("TEST");`

Comment: Yes of course. But this way I'd have to create a new instance of **each** existing interface implementation on **each** method invocation. That's not very suitable.

Comment: Are all of your `supports` methods implemented as `val.equals(someConstant)`?

Comment: Note: if all you have is `List<Class<MyService>> list`, you can't store anything except `MyService.class` (and null) in that list. So, you don't actually have any implementations of the method.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes they are all similar liek this.

Comment: @membersound then you could annotate the classes with `@Supports(constant)`, and get that reflectively.

Comment: That's great. Is there a way I could force any implementation of `MyService` having to define that annotation?

Comment: You can check when adding the implementation class if the annotation is presend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an Annotation `@Supports` for example that you can annotate your implementations with.

This Annotation may look like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Supports {

    String value();
}
```

By using `Class.isAnnotationPresent` you can check wether or not the implementation has the neede annotation and using `Class.getAnnotation` you get the annotation and can access the `value()` method to get the supported value.

Comment: I had guessed that `supports()` did more than `return value.equals(SOME_CONSTANT)`. I suppose I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you should do instead  `List<MyInterface>`  because you NEED to call the method of all the elements in the list

```
List<MyInterface> list = Arrays.asList(new MyImpl(), new MyImpl2());
String val = "TEST";

for (MyInterface x : list) {
    if (x.supports(val)) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need a fresh instance of the service on each execution. So I cannot put service instances into the list. I cannot reuse them.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for can't be done, given the API of your MyService.

The *only* way to find out whether a given class supports a string value, is to call `supports()` which is a non-static method. So you have to create an instance in order to invoke it.

Java doesn't let you define static methods in interfaces.

My advice is not to fight this, and take it as an indication that there's something wrong with your design. You would be better off *not* having a list of `Class<?>`, but instead have a list of `MyInterface`. Make them stateless and re-entrant, then you can easily call `supports()` and `process()`.

```
for(MyInterface obj : objs) {
    if(obj.supports(s)) {
        obj.process(s);
    }
}
```

This is a very common pattern especially in frameworks like Spring. You'd create that list of `MyInterface` objects at init time, and reuse it for the lifetime of the program.

If you *must* create a new instance each time, create a corresponding factory object for each one, and instead of a list of types, have a list of `MyInterfaceFactory`:

```
public class MyInterfaceImplFactory implements MyInterfaceFactory {
   public boolean supports(String s) {
        // hard code this here
   }

   public MyInterfaceImpl newInstance() {
       return new MyInterfaceImpl();
   }
}
```

...

```
for(MyInterfaceFactory factory : factories) {
    if(factory.supports(s)) {
        MyInterface obj = factory.newInstance();
        obj.process(s);
    }
}
```

(If you have so many of these that writing them becomes repetitive, you could do it more dynamically - but start by doing it the dumb way).

---

If you're determined to have a list of classes, that you can examine at runtime:

- you could standardise on a static `supports()` method that's not declared in the interface. You would have to call this through Reflection, and do without Java's type-safety.
- you might be able to do something with custom annotations

But don't do either of these if you have any freedom.

Comment: Well with this I'm getting all classes defining that interface. But I'm not actually executing the interface method `supports()`. But that is crucial because this method defines if the implementation could be used at all.

Comment: With apologies to the upvoter, I have completely rewritten this.